# Using Django time/date widgets in custom form

Tags: python, django

How can I use the nifty JavaScript date and time widgets that the default admin uses with my custom view?

I have looked through [the Django forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), and it briefly mentions django.contrib.admin.widgets, but I don't know how to use it?

Here is my template that I want it applied on.

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    <table>
        {% for f in form %}
           <tr> <td> {{ f.name }}</td> <td>{{ f }}</td> </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Product">
</form>
```

Also, I think it should be noted that I haven't really written a view up myself for this form, I am using a generic view. Here is the entry from the url.py:

```
(r'^admin/products/add/$', create_object, {'model': Product, 'post_save_redirect': ''}),
```

And I am relevantly new to the whole Django/MVC/MTV thing, so please go easy...

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: For date widgets, there are a few simple alternatives. I posted some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108038)

Comment: An alternative to this is to use HTML5 date/time pickers that work in modern browsers without any Javascript - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70800722/182604

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The growing complexity of this answer over time, and the many hacks required, probably ought to caution you against doing this at all. It's relying on undocumented internal implementation details of the admin, is likely to break again in future versions of Django, and is no easier to implement than just finding another JS calendar widget and using that.

That said, here's what you have to do if you're determined to make this work:

1. Define your own `ModelForm` subclass for your model (best to put it in forms.py in your app), and tell it to use the `AdminDateWidget` / `AdminTimeWidget` / `AdminSplitDateTime` (replace 'mydate' etc with the proper field names from your model):

   ```
    from django import forms
    from my_app.models import Product
    from django.contrib.admin import widgets                                       

    class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Product
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['mydate'].widget = widgets.AdminDateWidget()
            self.fields['mytime'].widget = widgets.AdminTimeWidget()
            self.fields['mydatetime'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()
   ```
2. Change your URLconf to pass `'form_class': ProductForm` instead of `'model': Product` to the generic `create_object` view (that'll mean `from my_app.forms import ProductForm` instead of `from my_app.models import Product`, of course).
3. In the head of your template, include `{{ form.media }}` to output the links to the Javascript files.
4. And the hacky part: the admin date/time widgets presume that the i18n JS stuff has been loaded, and also require core.js, but don't provide either one automatically.  So in your template above `{{ form.media }}` you'll need:

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_admin/jsi18n/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/core.js"></script>
   ```

You may also wish to use the following admin CSS (thanks [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/719583#719583) for mentioning this):

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/forms.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/base.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/global.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/widgets.css"/>
```

This implies that Django's admin media (`ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`) is at /media/admin/ - you can change that for your setup.  Ideally you'd use a context processor to pass this values to your template instead of hardcoding it, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

This also requires that the URL /my_admin/jsi18n/ be manually wired up to the django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog view (or null_javascript_catalog if you aren't using I18N).  You have to do this yourself instead of going through the admin application so it's accessible regardless of whether you're logged into the admin (thanks [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/408230#408230) for pointing this out).  Sample code for your URLconf:

```
(r'^my_admin/jsi18n', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog'),
```

Lastly, if you are using Django 1.2 or later, you need some additional code in your template to help the widgets find their media:

```
{% load adminmedia %} /* At the top of the template. */

/* In the head section of the template. */
<script type="text/javascript">
window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{% filter escapejs %}{% admin_media_prefix %}{% endfilter %}";
</script>
```

Thanks [lupefiasco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/2818128#2818128) for this addition.

Comment: Most helpful post online for doing this but having finally got date/time widget appear and populating field am now going to take it out because despite having required=False in the form field it now shows the message "Enter a valid date/time." for my not required field if I leave it blank.  Back to jquery for me.

Comment: Is this the way to go on Django 1.1.1?

Comment: @Ignacio I haven't tested this for quite a while, so YMMV. I'm not aware of any easier way that's been introduced since, in any case.

Comment: In Django 1.2 RC1 and later, you need to make a small change to the above.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/2818128#2818128

Comment: Do you know if this still applies to Django 1.4? Although I'm convinced to go with jQuery's datepicker, I'm curious if the Django team might have made their widget more publicly available. (I suspect not, as this QA seems to be the most documentation around)

Comment: There has been no movement towards making the admin widgets more easily reusable outside the admin, and I wouldn't guess that there will be any. It would be a lot of work, and there are much higher priority items to work on. (I'm part of the Django core team, btw).

Comment: this is great answer and it worked for me in django version 1.4. but recently i needed to convert django 1.4 to 1.5. now its giving me error that adminmedia is not valid library. kindly help me how to solve my problem

Comment: You should probably move that very last paragraph directly to the top of your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the standard form Media class instead of hacking the template manually?

Comment: You're right that it is easier/safer to use a 3rd party JS date/time picker, but there are many to choose from. I suggest [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) as it exists as a standalone package and is very simple to set up.

Comment: Doesn't use of the `AdminSplitDateTime` widget require using `SplitDateTimeField`? Using this solution, I get the error described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/58932440 (this answer was written a long time ago, so maybe this is only an issue for Django >= 2)

Answer (score 67):

As the solution is hackish, I think using your own date/time widget with some JavaScript is more feasible.

Comment: I agree. I tried doing this a few months ago with my django project. I eventually gave up and just added my own with jQueryUI. Took all of 10 minutes to get it working.

Comment: For the record, I agree, I've upvoted this answer, and I've never actually used the technique in my answer in a production site ;-)

Answer (score 14):

I find myself referencing this post a lot, and found that the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types) defines a *slightly* less hacky way to override default widgets.

(*No need to override the ModelForm's __init__ method*)

However, you still need to wire your JS and CSS appropriately as Carl mentions.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from my_app.models import Product
from django.contrib.admin import widgets                                       


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mydate = forms.DateField(widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget)
    mytime = forms.TimeField(widget=widgets.AdminTimeWidget)
    mydatetime = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=widgets.AdminSplitDateTime)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

Reference [Field Types](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) to find the default form fields.

Comment: I disagree that this approach is less hackish. It looks nicer, sure, but you are completely overriding the form fields generated by the model form, which could also erase options from the model fields, like help_text. Overriding __init__ only changes the widget and leaves the rest of the form field as it was.

Answer (score 13):

My head code for 1.4 version(some new and some removed)

```
{% block extrahead %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/css/forms.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/css/base.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/css/global.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/css/widgets.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/actions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: awesome . i was trying this from past 2 weeks and this help me thanks alot

Comment: using {{ STATIC_URL }} or {% load staticfiles %} with {% static 'admin/js/core.js' %}... is required for Django 1.4+, as the whole MEDIA_URL namespace was deprecated and removed. the /admin/jsi18n resolves properly if you have ^admin/ mapped in server/urls.py

Comment: nice stuff, useful in the case of Django 1.4

Answer (score 12):

Yep, I ended up overriding the /admin/jsi18n/ url.

Here's what I added in my urls.py.  Make sure it's above the /admin/ url

```
    (r'^admin/jsi18n', i18n_javascript),
```

And here is the i18n_javascript function I created.

```
from django.contrib import admin
def i18n_javascript(request):
  return admin.site.i18n_javascript(request)
```

Comment: Oh, very good point.  I'll add this to my answer above so it's easier for people to find before they have trouble.

Answer (score 10):

Starting in Django 1.2 RC1, if you're using the Django admin date picker widge trick, the following has to be added to your template, or you'll see the calendar icon url being referenced through "/missing-admin-media-prefix/".

```
{% load adminmedia %} /* At the top of the template. */

/* In the head section of the template. */
<script type="text/javascript">
window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{% filter escapejs %}{% admin_media_prefix %}{% endfilter %}";
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

## For Django >= 2.0

> *Note: Using admin widgets for date-time fields is not a good idea as admin style-sheets can conflict with your site style-sheets in case you are using bootstrap or any other CSS frameworks. If you are building your site on bootstrap use my bootstrap-datepicker widget [django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus](https://github.com/monim67/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus).*

**Step 1:** Add `javascript-catalog` URL to your project's (not app's) `urls.py` file.

```
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog

urlpatterns = [
    path('jsi18n', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
]
```

**Step 2:** Add required JavaScript/CSS resources to your template.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/admin/css/widgets.css' %}">
<style>.calendar>table>caption{caption-side:unset}</style><!--caption fix for bootstrap4-->
{{ form.media }}        {# Form required JS and CSS #}
```

**Step 3:** Use admin widgets for date-time input fields in your `forms.py`.

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from .models import Product

class ProductCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'publish_date', 'publish_time', 'publish_datetime']
        widgets = {
            'publish_date': widgets.AdminDateWidget,
            'publish_time': widgets.AdminTimeWidget,
            'publish_datetime': widgets.AdminSplitDateTime,
        }
```

Comment: As described in the other answer, another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392329) I believe the use of `AdminSplitDateTime` requires the use of `SplitDateTimeField`---otherwise, you'll run into issues when submitting (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58932440/)

Answer (score 7):

Complementing the answer by Carl Meyer, I would like to comment that you need to put that header in some valid block (inside the header) within your template.

```
{% block extra_head %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/forms.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/base.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/global.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/widgets.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>

{{ form.media }}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I also found this link useful: http://groups.google.ca/group/django-users/msg/1a40cf5f153cd23e

Answer (score 5):

The below will also work as a last resort if the above failed

```
class PaymentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Payments

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'].widget = SelectDateWidget()
```

Same as

```
class PaymentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Payments
```

put this in your forms.py `from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget`

Comment: it gives me error 'DateField' object has no attribute 'needs_multipart_form'

Answer (score 5):

Another simple solution for **Django 3 (3.2) in 2021** ;) cause andyw's solution doesn't work in Firefox...

```
{% load static %}

{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/cancel.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/forms.css' %}">
<script src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}

<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Сохранить">
</form>
```

and you'll able to use your form.
example:

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
date_time = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=widgets.AdminSplitDateTime)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another 2020 solution, inspired by @Sandeep's. Using the MinimalSplitDateTimeMultiWidget found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/andytwoods/76f18f5ddeba9192d51dccc922086e43?fbclid=IwAR1x4GbeHLMQypWKaYPGn55r92-uCmJZqLUf4kEAGeX4DTgalt2GQUNY7oQ), in our Form as below, we can use modern browser date and time selectors (via eg 'type': 'date'). We don't need any JS.

```
class EditAssessmentBaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Assessment
        fields = '__all__'

    begin = DateTimeField(widget=MinimalSplitDateTimeMultiWidget())
```

[image]

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
Do you have working app example?

Comment: I initialized it using this code:
date_created = forms.DateTimeField(widget=MinimalSplitDateTimeMultiWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
But it did not work

Comment: you need to provide more info @ARKhan

Comment: @ABHAYKOTAL
@ARKhan
replace the code with this
` date_attrs = attrs or {}
  time_attrs = attrs or {}`

Comment: I updated the gist to reflect @DanieleStoDomingo's fix

Comment: This works great in Apr 2021. Easiest way to get what you need

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Although browser support for `<input type="datetime-local">` is not ideal yet, it is quite good for `"date"` and `"time"` types, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#browser_compatibility).

Comment: An updated solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70800722/182604

Answer (score 3):

What about just assigning a class to your widget and then binding that class to the JQuery datepicker?

Django forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = MyModel

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['my_date_field'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'datepicker'
```

And some JavaScript for the template:

```
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660929/how-do-you-change-the-default-widget-for-all-django-date-fields-in-a-modelform

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution and workaround for **SplitDateTime** with **required=False**:

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms

class SplitDateTimeJSField(forms.SplitDateTimeField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SplitDateTimeJSField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.widget.widgets[0].attrs = {'class': 'vDateField'}
        self.widget.widgets[1].attrs = {'class': 'vTimeField'}  


class AnyFormOrModelForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'vDateField'}))
    time = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'vTimeField'}))
    timestamp = SplitDateTimeJSField(required=False,)
```

*form.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin_media/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin_media/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin_media/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>
```

*urls.py*

```
(r'^admin/jsi18n/', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog'),
```

Comment: I have also filled a ticket to fix the SplitDateTime widgets
http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12303

Answer (score 1):

I use this, it's great, but I have 2 problems with the template:

1. I see the calendar icons **twice** for every filed in template.
2. And for TimeField I have '**Enter a valid date.**'

   [image: Here is a screenshot of the Form]

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    create_date=models.DateField(blank=True)
    start_time=models.TimeField(blank=False)
    end_time=models.TimeField(blank=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Guide
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class GuideForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_time = forms.DateField(widget=widgets.AdminTimeWidget)
    end_time = forms.DateField(widget=widgets.AdminTimeWidget)
    create_date = forms.DateField(widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget)
    class Meta:
        model=Guide
        fields=['name','categorie','thumb']
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django 10.
myproject/urls.py:
at the beginning of urlpatterns

```
  from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
.
.
.]
```

In my template.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

    <script src="{% static "js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
    {# Loading internazionalization for js #}
    {% load i18n admin_modify %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/admin/js/jquery.init.js" %}"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/admin/css/base.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/admin/css/forms.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/admin/css/login.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/admin/css/widgets.css" %}">



    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/admin/js/core.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/admin/js/actions.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/admin/js/calendar.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js" %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Django Setup : 1.11
Bootstrap: 3.3.7

Since none of the answers are completely clear, I am sharing my template code which presents no errors at all.

**Top Half of template:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
    <title>Add Interview</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/forms.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/widgets.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
```

**Bottom Half:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/actions.min.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

June 3, 2020 (All answers didn't worked, you can try this solution I used. Just for TimeField)

Use simple `Charfield` for time fields (**start** and **end** in this example) in forms.

**forms.py**

we can use `Form` or `ModelForm` here.

```
class TimeSlotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'HH:MM'}))
    end = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'HH:MM'}))

    class Meta:
        model = TimeSlots
        fields = ('start', 'end', 'provider')
```

Convert string input into time object in views.

```
import datetime
def slots():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = create_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():                
            slot = form.save(commit=False)
            start = form.cleaned_data['start']
            end = form.cleaned_data['end']
            start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M').time()
            end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M').time()
            slot.start = start
            slot.end = end
            slot.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The most cleanest way (tested with Django 3.2):

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminSplitDateTime
from django import forms


class MyCustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    custom_datetime = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=AdminSplitDateTime())

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("custom_datetime",)


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def my_custom_admin_view(self, request):
        form = MyCustomForm()
        admin_form = admin.helpers.AdminForm(form, [], {}, model_admin=self)
        media = self.media + admin_form.media
        context = {
            "media": media,
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, "my_custom_template.html", context)
```

In the `my_custom_template.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block extrastyle %}
{{ block.super }}
{{ media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
{{ form.as_p  }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```