# django : using admin datepicker

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, date

I'm trying to use the admin datepicker in my own django forms.

Roughly following the discussion here : http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg72138.html

I've

a) In my forms.py included the line

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
```

b) and used the widget like this :

```
date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget())
```

c) And in my actual template I've added :

```
{{form.media}}
```

To include the js / styles etc.

However, when I try to view my form I get no nice widget; just an ordinary text box. And the Firefox javascript error console shows me :

gettext is not defined in calendar.js (line 26)

and

addEvent is not defined in DateTimeShortcuts.js (line 254)

Any suggestions? Is this a bug in Django's own javascript library?

Update : Basically, need to include the core and (or fake) the i18lization

Update 2 : Carl points out this is pretty much a duplicate of [Using Django time/date widgets in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/38916#38916) (although starting from a different position)

Comment: This question is a duplicate.  See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/38916#38916

Comment: thanks ... funny, that didn't pop up in any of "Related Questions" Either in the side-bar here or when I was writing the question

Comment: The answer to the question Carl Meyer references, makes clear that this is an answer which requires a lot of work, more than just implementing your own datepicker using jQuery or some other well-known library.

Comment: A few years later, there are some alternatives now, like [using the browser's built-in date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108038). No javascript or css required.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not a bug.

It's trying to call the gettext() internationalization function in js. You can do js internationalization much like you do it in python code or templates, it's only a less known feature.

If you don't use js internationalization in your project you can just put.

```
<script>function gettext(txt){ return txt }</script>
```

in your top template so the js interpreter doesn't choke.

This is a hacky way to solve it I know.

Edit:

Or you can include the exact jsi18n js django admin references to get it working even with other languages. I don't know which one it is.

This was posted on django-users today:

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/2f529966472c479d#

Maybe it was you, anyway, just in case.

Comment: thanks ... yes, it's hacky, but it's got me past that problem as a temporary fix

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was well written and made the process clear, and feel a little less hacky.

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved the first half by explicitly adding these lines to my template :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jsi18n/"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin_media/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin_media/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
```

But it still reports not knowing gettext

Comment: there's no point in adding jsi18n if you don't have it in your url mappings. that's where the gettext function will be if you do add the right thing in urls.py: urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^jsi18n/(?P<packages>\S+?)/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog'),
)

Comment: good point .. though I found that line in the admin form too. So I presume it works on this server. In which case ... why for them if not me. Maybe because it's relative in the admin tree there.

Comment: :) yes, but it's a relative uri, so  if you can figure out what it resolves to in the admin templates, you can put it as an absolute url and have it work. I think this way event proper internationalization of the datepicker will work.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following works for you:

```
<link href="/media/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/core.js"></script>
{{ form.media }}
```