# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField Widget not Rendering

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to use the built-in django admin widget `ModelMultipleChoiceField` to render something like this in a form:

[image]

I have followed others' recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698435/django-multi-select-widget), and have reviewed the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/). but I am getting a half-complete widget; only one box is showing, and all of the associated buttons don't appear:

[image]

In addition, when the page loads, the following error is given:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined at (index):1665
```

Here is the line within `index` that is causing the error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    addEvent(window, "load", function(e) {SelectFilter.init("id_employee_selection", "__unicode__", 0, "/static/admin/"); });
</script>
```

I cannot find `addEvent.js` anywhere within the django library, even though it is referenced on some django [tickets](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2651).

For reference, below are my `form` and `HTML`

FORM:

```
from django import forms

class EventAttendeesForm(forms.Form):

    from employees.models import Employee
    from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

    employee_selection = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                    queryset=Employee.objects.all(),
                    widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("__unicode__", is_stacked=False, attrs={'rows':20})
                    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventAttendeesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['employee_selection'].label = "Employees"
```

HTML SNIPPET:

```
<link href="/static/admin/css/widgets.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsi18n/"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>

<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type='submit' value='Add Item(s)' />
</form>

{{ media }}
```

**How can I correctly render the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` widget?**

I have tried this [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660898/django-using-admin-datepicker/660986#660986) but it doesn't work.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: it is critical to have all `form.media` and associated javascripts load before the form loads.

So, instead of:

```
<link href="/static/admin/css/widgets.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsi18n/"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>

<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type='submit' value='Add Item(s)' />
</form>

{{ media }}
```

Do this (scripts + `form.media` placed before `form`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsi18n/"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>

{{ media }}

<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type='submit' value='Add Item(s)' />
</form>
```