# How to use a DatePicker in a ModelForm in django?

Tags: python, django, datepicker, modelform

I am using django 3.0 and I am trying to display a datepicker widget in my ModelForm, but I can't figure out how (all I can get is text field). I have tried looking for some solutions, but couldn't find any. This is how my Model and my ModelForm look like:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
  start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today, null=True)
  owner = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
  type = models.ForeignKey(MembershipType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class MembershipForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Membership
    fields = ['owner', 'start_date', 'type']
    widgets = {
        'start_date': forms.DateInput
    }
```

And this is my html:

```
<form class="container" action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior: the `DateInput` is just a `text` box with an optional format: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#dateinput

Comment: I know that, but I was wondering how can I use the DatePicker widget.

Comment: You could use the admin datepicker, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38601) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/660898).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. A [**`DateInput`** widget [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#dateinput) is just a `<input type="text">` element with an optional `format` parameter.

You can make use of a package, like for example [**`django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus`** [pypi]](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/)
, and then define a form with the `DatePickerInput`:

```
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput

class MembershipForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Membership
    fields = ['owner', 'start_date', 'type']
    widgets = {
        'start_date': DatePickerInput
    }
```

In the template you will need to render the media of the form and load the bootstrap css and javascript:

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
{{ form.media }}

<form class="container" action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: saying, invalid block {5 bootstrap_css %} and {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}

Comment: @djangodeveloper: that is because you wrote `{5` instead of `{%`...

Comment: oh, sorry, removed but still facing the issue. what I want to do is, update a form in which there are datepicker options, at the moment not getting the datepicker worked

Comment: @djangodeveloper: what issue?

Comment: Invalid block tag on line 3: 'bootstrap_css'

Comment: @djangodeveloper: you need to `{% load bootstrap4 %}` first to load the template tag...

Comment: 'bootstrap' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Comment: when I load bootstrap_tags, it doesn't throws an error related to bootstrap is not a registered tag library

Comment: and same goes for bootstrap4 or bootstrap5

Comment: @djangodeveloper: you need to install the package first, and add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS`. See the *installing* section of https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/

Comment: installed it. now getting issue of 'bootstrap_javascript' received unexpected keyword argument 'jquery'

Comment: @djangodeveloper: what if you remove `jquery='full'`

Comment: I had to downgrade the bootstrap version. jquery = "Full" was working with bootstrap4 only. in bootstrap5, it need to be removed

Answer (score 15):

Although [@willem-van-onsem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61078078) is great, there are a few alternatives that do not require additional dependencies.

A few options, in order of increasing effort:

1. Use a [SelectDateWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#selectdatewidget) instead of the default [DateInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#datefield) (*no* JavaScript required):

   ```py
   class MyForm(forms.Form):
       date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
   ```
2. Use the browser's built-in date picker, by implementing a customized widget that uses the HTML [<input type="date">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) element (*no* JavaScript required):

   ```py
   class MyDateInput(forms.widgets.DateInput):
       input_type = 'date'

   class MyForm(forms.Form):
       date = forms.DateField(widget=MyDateInput())
   ```

   or, alternatively:

   ```py
   class MyForm(forms.Form):
       date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs=dict(type='date')))
   ```
3. Use the date picker from `django.contrib.admin`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38601) in detail. In short, there are a few things you would need:

   ```py
   from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
   ...
   class MyForm(forms.Form):
       date = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget())
   ```

   then, to make this work, add the following dependencies to your template `<head>`:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/widgets.css' %}" />
   <script src="{% static 'admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>  {# see note below #}
   {{ form.media }}  {# this adds 'calendar.js' and 'DateTimeShortcuts.js' #}
   ```

   Now there's one catch: the `admin:jsi18n` url only works for users with admin access, so you may need to replace this and define an alternative path in your `urls.py`, e.g.:

   ```py
   from django.views import i18n
   ...
   urlpatterns = [
       ...,
       path('jsi18n/', i18n.JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='jsi18n'),
   ]
   ```

Finally, here's what the widgets look like (on firefox):

[image: date picker examples]

Personally I like the second option best. It also allows us to specify initial, minimum and maximum values (in django you can do this e.g. using the `attrs` argument). Here's a quick snippet to show the HTML element in action:

```html
<input type="date" value="2021-09-09" min="2021-09-09">
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3367091

Answer (score 1):

Django 4.0. Leaving this here incase it helps someone else.
This will set the minimum date and default value to today's date and should be used in forms.py. In my case I use crispy forms in my .html to render the field.

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
    
class DateForm(forms.ModelForm):
   target_Date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'min': today, 'value': today, 'type': 'date'}), required=True)

class Meta:
    model = DateForm
    fields = ['target_Date']
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, this is expected since its just a special text field.

An alternative I prefer is using `django-widget-tweaks` as this pushes front-end customizations back to your template instead of editing forms.py on the backend. Saving/testing is also faster since the app doesn't have to reload with each save.

Install to your environment:

```
pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

Add to installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   "widget_tweaks",
]
```

Add to your template:

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
```

Use `render_field` with input tag attributes to customize your field. Eg below using bootstrap 5. Notice how we can specify attributes such as `type` and `class` within the template tag:

```
<div class="col-2">
   <label for="{{ form.date.id_for_label }}" class="col-form-label">{{ form.year.label }}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
   {% render_field form.year type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" %}
<div>
```

[image: widget tweaks date]