# Making Django forms.DateField show use local date format

Tags: django, forms, strftime, datefield

I'm trying to find an easy way to build forms which show dates in the Australian format (dd/mm/yyyy).  This was the only way I could find to do it.  It seems like there should be a better solution.

Things to note:

- Created a new widget which renders date value in dd/mm/yyyy format
- Created new date field to prepend the locate date format string to the list of values it tries to use

I imagine the ideal solution would be a datefield which automatically localised but that didn't work for me (strftime didn't seem to be unicode friendly but I didn't try very hard)

Am I missing something?  Is there a more elegant solution?  Is this a robust approach?

```
from models import *
from django import forms
import datetime

class MyDateWidget(forms.TextInput):

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):

            if isinstance(value, datetime.date):
                    value=value.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

            return super(MyDateWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)


class MyDateField(forms.DateField):

    widget = MyDateWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MyDateField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.input_formats = ("%d/%m/%Y",)+(self.input_formats)


class ExampleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
            model=MyModel
            fields=('name', 'date_of_birth')

    date_of_birth = MyDateField()
```

Comment: One simple alternative is to rely on a javascript calendar widget to do the localisation.  One we use simply hides my date field and creates another with the local formatting specified.

Comment: Any info on particular widgets and hooking up a widget?

Comment: I suppose I should refer to the stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114068/best-javascript-calendar-control.

Comment: My answer below provides a much more generalized approach than overriding the format for the widget.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Granted, I'm not a django/python Jedi, but...

I don't think there is anything wrong with your approach. It is a clean read.

You might not need to create your own widget just to render the date in the proper format on the first form display. Just use the `format` parameter for the `DateInput` widget and you should be OK. So in your MyDateField class I would just do:

```
class MyDateField(forms.DateField):

    widget = forms.DateInput(format="%d/%m/%Y")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDateField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.input_formats = ("%d/%m/%Y",)+(self.input_formats)
```

You could use `formfield_callback` (See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660929/how-do-you-change-the-default-widget-for-all-django-date-fields-in-a-modelform) for this distantly related question), meaning:

```
def customize_fields(f):
    if isinstance(f, DateTimeField):
        datetime_field=forms.DateTimeField(widget=
            forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %h:%i'))
        date_field.input_formats = ("%d/%m/%Y %h:%i",)+
            (date_field.input_formats)
        return datetime_field
    elif isinstance(f, DateField):
        date_field=forms.DateField(widget=
            forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'))
        date_field.input_formats = ("%d/%m/%Y",)+
            (date_field.input_formats)
        return date_field
    else:
        return f.formfield()

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    formfield_callback = customize_fields

    class Meta:
        model = ...
```

Doing that completely eliminates the need for your `MyDateField` class, but might introduce - if you want every single form class to call `customize_fields` - the need for a ModelForm descendent, implementing `formfield_callback=customize_fields` as the new base for all your form classes.

My problem with using the `formfield_callback` mechanism is two-fold:

1. It is less readable and relies in knowledge of the inner workings of ModelForms. I can't find actual documentation on formfield_callback anywhere...
2. If you ever need to redefine a model field in a ModelForm, say to make the field not required for that particular instance of the form, like so:

   ```
      class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
          formfield_callback = customize_fields
          foo = forms.DateField(required=false)

          class Meta:
              model = Bar
   ```

   you are overwriting the form field returned by customize_fields, hence completely losing the customization.

I think your approach is more readable.

Answer (score 6):

I've used this simple approach before: just set the 'format' attribute of the DateField.widget in the init of the Form:

```
    class ExampleForm(ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = MyModel

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['date_of_birth'].widget.format = '%d/%m/%Y'

            # at the same time, set the input format on the date field like you want it:
            self.fields['date_of_birth'].input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the custom widget stuff can be bypassed.

Here's an excerpt from `django/forms/widgets.py`:

```
class DateInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, format=None):
        super(DateInput, self).__init__(attrs)
        if format:
            self.format = format
            self.manual_format = True
        else:
            self.format = formats.get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS')[0]
            self.manual_format = False
```

You'll notice that the format of the widget is set using the format module. The format module is selected depending on the locale. If you're browsing from the US, Django will, by default, select `django.conf.formats.locale.en.formats.py`. Here you will find the default format:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
    # '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
    # '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
    # '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
    # '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
)
```

As you can see in the first code block, Django selects the first of these. The thorough approach to changing the format is to create your own format module, overriding Django's default for the locale in question. For that, look into [FORMAT_MODULE_PATH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#format-module-path). If all you're trying to do is override the default date format, I say save yourself some time and monkey patch. I added this to my settings file and everything appears to be working splendidly with my preferred default format:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%Y-%m-%d',
                      '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y', '%d %b %Y',
                      '%d %b, %Y', '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',
                      '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y')
from django.conf.locale.en import formats
formats.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = DATE_INPUT_FORMATS
```

Answer (score 0):

In my form I'me using:

```
def today():
    from datetime import date
    return date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

when = models.DateField(u'Когда', default=today)
```