# Localization of Date formats in Django

Tags: django

I am working on an app that should support different languages and flavours such as American, British and German.

Now looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/localflavor/#united-states-of-america-us), e.g. there seem to be no direct support for American date format.  It seems this part needs to be done by hand.

So I kept digging into the documentation and found [this:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date)

```
{{ value|date:"D d M Y" }}
```

This doesn't seem to work well with forms though, when I tried this in my code:

```
{{form.birth_date|date:"D d M Y"}}
```

It seems the formatting needs to be set right at the form field itself.

More research showed a similar question was asked in Stackoverflow in [2009:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453413/making-django-forms-datefield-show-use-local-date-format)

This solution could work, but it looks quite engaging for such a simple problem. Django has come a long way since 2009, so I wonder if there is a better way of doing it right into ModelForm?

Let say we have the following code:

**Model:**

```
class ConversationHistory(models.Model):
    contact_date        = models.DateField(_(u"Conversation Date"))
```

**Form:**

```
class ConversationForm(ModelForm):        
    class Meta:
        model = ConversationHistory
```

Could I just add the following to ModelForm:

```
widgets = { 'contact_date': forms.DateInput(format='M d, Y') }
```

is this the right way of localization?  What if I wanted to change the format to Brtish English or German? So I have the feeling I am missing here something...

Many Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

I have now tried this:

```
widgets = { 'contact_date': forms.DateInput(format='SHORT_DATE_FORMAT') }
```

But the date shows as SHORT_DATE_FORMAT.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe [SHORT_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-SHORT_DATE_FORMAT)

Answer (score 0):

[You're looking for the `x` format.](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) Or worst case you just I18Nize the format and let the translator figure it out.

Comment: but when I leave out the format altogether why am I seeing 2012/07/11 instead of American date format? In settings I have set the language to `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'`. The whole thing doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a solution for this with `dojo` for 2YRS!!! And I finally manged to find the the following works if you are using the `dojango` intergration.

```
someDate = DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'constraints':'{datePattern:\'dd/MM/yyyy\', strict:true}'))
```

*forms.py*

I don't know if that helps