# Cannot read a greek localized date in django

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization, django-forms

I want to read a localized greek date for my django project. The correct format for greek dates is dd/mm/yy (f.e. 22/2/2012).

Now, I have set my project language (in settings.py) to 'el' (for greek) and I have create a DateInput with localize=True. If I try to enter a dd/mm/yy format I get an error (invalid format) response. On the other hand if I try to enter a mm/dd/yy format it works fine. Also, if I change my project language from 'el' to 'en-GB' (for UK english), the dd/mm/yy format *is accepted successfully*.

Before going crazy, I took a look at the django source code and more specifically to the file:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/el/formats.py

which should contain the formats for greece but foun out that the `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` **was commented out**. On the other hand, the same file for UK English (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/en_GB/formats.py) contained two valid entries for `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`. Could that be related to the problem ?

I know that I can set the widget format (like described in this question [Making Django forms.DateField show use local date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453413/making-django-forms-datefield-show-use-local-date-format)) however I'd really like to use the L10N capabilities and *not* add different date formats for each language I want to support  :(

Comment: `"%x"` will give you the locale defined format string ... but you then have to make sure you actually set the locale ...

Comment: I have a normal django form with a normal dateinput. I want to be able to read a date in the 22/02/2012 format without getting a validation error. Where would "%x" help me ?