# Django Problem inheriting formfield_callback in ModelForms

Tags: django, django-forms

I've only been using Django for a couple of weeks now, so I may be approaching this all kinds of wrong, but:

I have a base ModelForm that I put some boilerplate stuff in to keep things as DRY as possible, and all of my actual ModelForms just subclass that base form.  This is working great for `error_css_class = 'error'` and `required_css_class = 'required'` but `formfield_callback = add_css_classes` isn't working like I would expect it to.

## forms.py

```
# snippet I found
def add_css_classes(f, **kwargs):
    field = f.formfield(**kwargs)
    if field and 'class' not in field.widget.attrs:
        field.widget.attrs['class'] = '%s' % field.__class__.__name__.lower()
    return field

class BaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    formfield_callback = add_css_classes  # not working

    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
    class Meta:
        pass

class TimeLogForm(BaseForm):
    # I want the next line to be in the parent class
    # formfield_callback = add_css_classes
    class Meta(BaseForm.Meta):
        model = TimeLog
```

The end goal is to slap some jquery datetime pickers on forms with a class of datefield/timefield/datetimefield. I want all of the date time fields within the app to use the same widget, so I opted to do it this way than explicitly doing it for each field in every model. Adding an extra line to each form class isn't that big of a deal, but it just bugged me that I couldn't figure it out. Digging around in the django source showed this is probably doing something I'm not understanding:

## django.forms.models

```
class ModelFormMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        formfield_callback = attrs.pop('formfield_callback', None)
```

But I don't know how `__init__` and `__new__` are all intermangled. In BaseForm I tried overriding `__init__` and setting formfield_callback before and after the call to super, but I'm guessing it needs to be somewhere in args or kwargs.

Comment: It doesn't work because *formfield_callback* is not a field of object. It's just a variable.

Comment: Is there a way to set it at runtime then? Or does `formfield_callback = attrs.pop('formfield_callback', None)` kill any chance of that in `ModelFormMetaclass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__new__ is called before object construction. Actually this is a *factory* method that returns the instance of a newly constructed object.

So there there are 3 key lines in *ModelFormMetaclass*:

```
formfield_callback = attrs.pop('formfield_callback', None) #1
fields = fields_for_model(opts.model, opts.fields, 
                                      opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback) #2
new_class.base_fields = fields #3
```

In the class we attach base_fields to our *form*.

Now let's look to *ModelForm class*:

```
class ModelForm(BaseModelForm):
    __metaclass__ = ModelFormMetaclass
```

This means that ModelFormMetaclass.__new__(...) will be called when we create a ModelForm instance to change the structure of the future instance. And attrs of __new__ (**def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)**) in *ModelFormMetaclass* is a dict of *all attributes* of *ModelForm class*.

So decision is to create new InheritedFormMetaclass for our case (inheriting it from *ModelFormMetaclass*). Don't forget to call ***new*** of the parent in *InheritedFormMetaclass*. Then create our *BaseForm class* and say:

```
__metaclass__ = InheritedFormMetaclass
```

In __new__(...) implementation of *InheritedFormMetaclass* we could do all we want.

If my answer is not detailed enough please let me know with help of comments.

Comment: +1 for neat stuff, -1 for what I think is overkill. Assuming I understand the problem, this can be solved simply by overriding BaseForm.__init__. Details in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may set widgets class like this:

```
class TimeLogForm(BaseForm):
# I want the next line to be in the parent class
# formfield_callback = add_css_classes
class Meta(BaseForm.Meta):
    model = TimeLog
    widgets = {
            'some_fields' : SomeWidgets(attrs={'class' : 'myclass'})
    }
```

Comment: The idea was that I didn't want to repeat writing that same Meta class in all of the forms, but rather just right it once and everything would inherit it. We've been slammed at work with php, so I haven't had a chance to dig into it, but I think s-zakharov was on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

For what you're trying to accomplish, I think you're better off just looping through the fields on form init. For example,

```
class BaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for name, field in self.fields.items():
      field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'error'
```

Clearly you'll need a little more logic for your specific case. If you want to use the approach that sergzach suggested (overkill for your particular problem I think), here's some code for you that will call formfield_callback on the base class in the case the subclass doesn't define it.

```
baseform_formfield_callback(field):
    # do some stuff
    return field.formfield()

class BaseModelFormMetaclass(forms.models.ModelFormMetaclass):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if not attrs.has_key('formfield_callback'):
            attrs['formfield_callback'] = baseform_formfield_callback
        new_class = super(BaseModelFormMetaclass, cls).__new__(
            cls, name, bases, attrs)
        return new_class

class BaseModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    __metaclass__ = OrganizationModelFormMetaclass
    # other form stuff
```

Finally, you might wanna look into crispy forms: https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms

Answer (score 0):

sergzach is correct that you have to use metaclasses; overriding `__init__` is not enough. The reason is that the metaclass for ModelForm (which will be called for all ModelForm subclasses unless you specify another metaclass in a subclass) takes the class definition, and using the values in the *class definition* creates a class with *class attributes*. For example, both META.fields and our formfield_callback is used to create form Fields with various option (like which widget).

That means AFAIU formfield_callback is a *parameter to the metaclass* used when creating your custom model form class, not some value used at runtime when actual form instances are created. That makes placing formfield_callback in `__init__` useless.

I solved a similiar problem with a custom metaclass like

```
from django.forms.models import ModelFormMetaclass

class MyModelFormMetaclass(ModelFormMetaclass):
    def __new__(cls,name,bases,attrs):
    attrs['formfield_callback']=my_callback_function
    return super(MyModelFormMetaclass,cls).__new__(cls,name,bases,attrs)
```

and in the base class for all my model forms setting the metaclass

```
class MyBaseModelForm(ModelForm):
    __metaclass__=MyModelFormMetaclass
    ...
```

which can be used like (at least in Django 1.6)

```
class MyConcreteModelForm(MyBaseModelForm):
    # no need setting formfield_callback here
    ...
```