# jQuery datepicker in Django admin without using django forms

Tags: django-admin

I have a datefield named `pub_date` in my django project. I want to use jQuery datepicker instead of default django datepicker **in django admin**. But I want to do it **without using django forms**. Is it possible to do that? I'm giving my code below.

**models.py**

```
   import datetime

   from django.db import models

   class Poll(models.Model):
       question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
       date     = models.DateField('Registration Date')
       pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.question

       def was_published_today(self):
           return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()
       was_published_today.short_description = 'Published today?'

   class Choice(models.Model):
       poll   = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
       choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
       votes  = models.IntegerField()

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.choice
```

**admin.py**

```
    from django.contrib import admin

    from poject.app.models import Poll, Choice

    class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Choice
        extra = 3

    class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fieldsets = [
            (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
            ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
        ]
        inlines        = [ChoiceInline]
        list_display   = ('question', 'pub_date', 'was_published_today')
        list_filter    = ['pub_date']
        search_fields  = ['question']
        date_hierarchy = 'pub_date'

    admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
    admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Is it possible to use **jquery datepicker** in the **DateField** and **DateTimeField** defined in the above models without using django forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a form widget you can override the datepicker by [overriding your admin change_form.html template](http://ilostmynotes.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-django-admin-time-and-date.html).

Comment: I have displayed jquery datepicker in django admin using this method. But I couldn't hide default django datepicker shortcuts. How to hide them or how to replace default django datepicker with jquery datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my question [Change the default widget for date fields in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516332/change-the-default-widget-for-date-fields-in-django-admin) about how to do this for all DateField instances.

If you don't want to touch forms, provide your own js/calendar.js and js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js - if you want to do this only for a particular model you'll need to override its change_form.html template and replace the default javascript files just there. What the javascript does is look for date(time) fields and insert the datepicker - yours would do the same, just with a different datepicker.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I tried the methods given in yr question. But I couldn't get them working. I'm a beginner in django and I'm not so clear about overriding default datepicker js. So if possible, can you please explain a little more detail to me with samples. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The other answer (a subset) has become more useful? Look at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js - admin (widgets) use DateTimeShortcuts.init() to append a "calendar icon" after every input field with class "vDateField". The actual calendar is drawn with https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/calendar.js - in your static folder just provide admin/js/calendar.js and admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js - then they will be used instead. Then mimick other DateTimeShortcuts functions.