# Django required field in model form

Tags: python, django, forms, model, widget

I have a form where a couple of fields are coming out as required when I don't want them too. Here is the form from models.py

```
class CircuitForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Circuit
        exclude = ('lastPaged',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CircuitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['begin'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()
        self.fields['end'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()
```

In the actual Circuit model, the fields are defined like this:

```
begin = models.DateTimeField('Start Time', null=True, blank=True)
end = models.DateTimeField('Stop Time', null=True, blank=True)
```

My views.py for this is here:

```
def addCircuitForm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CircuitForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/sla/all')
    form = CircuitForm()    
    return render_to_response('sla/add.html', {'form': form})
```

What can I do so that the two fields aren't required?

Comment: There is no way that these fields become required by changing the widgets. If models has (null=True, blank=True), the modelForm renders it as required=False.

Comment: Looks like you are right. The fields themselves aren't required but the Date and Time fields in the widget are required.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If you don't want to modify blank setting for your fields inside models (doing so will break normal validation in admin site), you can do the following in your Form class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CircuitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for key in self.fields:
        self.fields[key].required = False
```

The redefined constructor won't harm any functionality.

Answer (score 19):

> If the model field has blank=True, then required is set to False on the form field. Otherwise, required=True

Says so here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Looks like you are doing everything right.
You could check the value of `self.fields['end'].required`.

Comment: Note that some fields (e.g. `BooleanField`) have blank=True hard-coded in their constructor (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#BooleanField). So, setting blank=False will silently fail. You have to use `self.fields[…].required = True` in the form’s constructor to force required behaviour for those fields. See also https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22282.

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on DataGreed's answer, I created a Mixin that allows you to specify a `fields_required` variable on the `Meta` class like this:

```
class MyForm(RequiredFieldsMixin, ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']
        fields_required = ['field1']
```

Here it is:

```
class RequiredFieldsMixin():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        fields_required = getattr(self.Meta, 'fields_required', None)

        if fields_required:
            for key in self.fields:
                if key not in fields_required:
                    self.fields[key].required = False
```

Comment: What will happen if the user of this mixin will override `__init__` as well? will the mixin still work? how the multiple inheritance will be resolved?

Comment: @user3599803 when you override `__init__` you should always call `super()`, like it's done in my snippet.

Comment: So if I understand- I create a form and subclass MyForm. I call super from init(), which will call the mixin init, but when djangl form init get called?

Comment: Yes, there's other resources discussing this, you can also create a new question if you want, please keep the comments here on topic of this particular question.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an answer, but for anyone else who finds this via Google, one more bit of data: this is happening to me on a Model Form with a DateField. It has required set to False, the model has "null=True, blank=True" and the field in the form shows required=False if I look at it during the clean() method, but it's still saying I need a valid date format. I'm not using any special widget and I get the "Enter a valid date" message even when I explicitly set input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', ''] on the form field.

**EDIT:** Don't know if it'll help anyone else, but I solved the problem I was having. Our form has some default text in the field (in this case, the word "to" to indicate the field is the end date; the field is called "end_time"). I was specifically looking for the word "to" in the form's clean() method (I'd also tried the clean_end_time() method, but it never got called) and setting the value of the clean_data variable to None as suggested in [this Django ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11765). However, none of that mattered as (I guess) the model's validation had already puked on the invalid date format of "to" without giving me a chance to intercept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug when using the widgets:

workaround:
[Using Django time/date widgets in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/1833247#1833247)

or ticket 12303

Answer (score 0):

From the [model field documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/),

If you have a model as shown below,

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Use puns liberally',
    )
    content = models.TextField()
```

You can change the headline's form validation to `required=True` instead of `blank=False` as that of the model as defining the field as shown below.

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    headline = MyFormField(
        max_length=200,
        required=False,
        help_text='Use puns liberally',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['headline', 'content']
```

So answering the question,

```
class CircuitForm(ModelForm):
    begin = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)
    end = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)
        class Meta:
            model = Circuit
            exclude = ('lastPaged',)
```

this makes `begin` and `end` to `required=False`