# Django Model Forms - Setting a required field

Tags: django, django-forms

```
 15 class Profile(models.Model):
 16     """
 17     User profile model
 18     """
 19     user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
 20     country = models.CharField('Country', blank=True, null=True, default='',\
 21                                max_length=50, choices=country_list())
 22     is_active = models.BooleanField("Email Activated")
```

I have a model like above with `country` set to `blank=True, null=True`.

However, in the form that is presented to the end user, I required the country field to be completed.

So I redefine the field in the Model Form like this to 'force' it to become required:

```
 77 class ProfileEditPersonalForm(forms.ModelForm):
 78 
 79     class Meta:
 80         model = Profile
 81         fields = ('email',
 82                   'sec_email',  
 83                   'image',
 84                   'first_name',
 85                   'middle_name',
 86                   'last_name',
 87                   'country',
 88                   'number',
 89                   'fax',)
 90 
 98     country =  forms.ChoiceField(label='Country', choices = country_list())
```

So the country field is just an example (there are tons of them). Is there a better more DRY way of doing this?

Comment: Uh, yeah. Don't set it `blank` and `null`.

Comment: I kind of need to as I need to display a 'profile details' page for a new user who hasn't updated his profile for the first time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django required field in model form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134667/django-required-field-in-model-form)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can modify the fields in `__init__` in the form. This is DRY since the label, queryset and everything else will be used from the model. This can also be useful for overriding other things (e.g. limiting querysets/choices, adding a help text, changing a label, ...).

```
class ProfileEditPersonalForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (...)
```

Here is a blog post that describes the same "technique": http://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/07/24/useful-form-tricks-in-django/

Comment: I know `super(ProfileEditPersonalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` calls the `forms.ModelForm` parent class `__init__` method but why is it necessary?

Comment: In this case, it is necessary to call the super __init__ (i.e. ModelForm.__init__) to set up self.fields for this form instance. It also makes a bunch of other initialization that is necessary to use the form object. This is a standard OO practice, unless you are totally replacing a method, you probably need to call the super class method in some way.

Answer (score 13):

In Django 3.0 if you for example want to make email required in user registration form, you can set `required=True`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class MyForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True) # <- set here

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this, this is much cleaner and simpler than overriding `__init__()`.

Comment: Thank you! Been trying to figure this out for hours.