# is it possible to vanish all the validators from a FormField without overriding the field?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following environment in Django 1.5.1:

## forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-xlarge', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-xlarge', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-xlarge', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'mobile_phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-xlarge', 'placeholder': 'Mobile Phone'}),
            'office_phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-xlarge', 'placeholder': 'Office Phone'}),
        }

    GROUP_CHOICES = [(-1, '[Select]')]
    GROUP_CHOICES += [(group.id, group.name.capitalize()) for group in Group.objects.all()]

    username = forms.EmailField(
        label='Email Address',
        required=True,
        validators=[validate_email],
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-xlarge', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'})
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'input-xlarge', 'placeholder': 'Password'})
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password confirmation',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'input-xlarge', 'placeholder': 'Password confirmation'})
    )
    group = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Group',
        choices=GROUP_CHOICES
    )

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match')
        return password2

    def clean_group(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['group'] == '-1':
            raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required.')
        return self.cleaned_data['group']

    def clean_first_name(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['first_name'] == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required.')
        return self.cleaned_data['first_name']

    def clean_last_name(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['last_name'] == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required.')
        return self.cleaned_data['last_name']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if commit:
            user.save()
            user.groups.clear()
            user.groups.add(self.cleaned_data['group'])
            user.save()
        return user
```

## models.py

```
class User(auth.models.User):
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Mobile Phone',
        max_length=50
    )
    office_phone = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Office Phone',
        max_length=50
    )
```

I *ALTER* the *auth_user* to allow me insert usernames greater than 30 characters long so I would be able to use *email* as *username* (I already tried with *OneToOneField* and with custom model and those approach caused me more work than the expected so I'm not going to take that way)

## My questions:

1. I had to add first_name and last_name cleaners since auth.models.User doesn't have them as *required* and the widget object don't allow me to set a *required* attribute, is this the best approach?
2. I'm having just one problem, the *username* field still has a *MaxValueValidator* setting 30 at most. How could I vanish it without overriding it in the form. Since I'm using Class Based Views, overriding the fields won't initiate the *username* field with model data when I try to update the form via *UpdateView* class, leaving it empty. The remaining fields don't have any problem

Thanks and sorry if my english looks ugly!

Comment: As for point 1 [altering fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682804/django-model-forms-setting-a-required-field#answer-7683392) can be done on class initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found how to avoid this behavior, since MaxValueValidator was running on models side I overrode `clean_username` in forms.py and add `self._meta.exclude += ('username',)` to avoid being validated in models. Of course, if you don't have any `exclude` property in your Meta class then just use `self._meta.exclude = ('username',)`