# Django - forms - force user fill in nullable fields in form

Tags: django, forms

I've got a profile model with some nullable fields in order to create it easily, however, I'd like users to fill in all the form fields even if they are nullable when they try to edit it. Feel free to let me know if you need more info... Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Model Forms - Setting a required field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682804/django-model-forms-setting-a-required-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `required=True` to all your form fields manually

```
from django import forms

class YourForm(forms.Form):
    your_filed = forms.CharField(required=True)
    ...
```

or make it with  `__init__`

```
from django import forms

class YourForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].required = True
```