# Are ModelForms in django used only for POSTing?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

ModelForms are a nice way to prevent repeating the definitions of models one creates. What I would like to do is take advantage of that feature and use it for more than just processing POST requests. I use forms a lot for validation.

Example:

Say you have a User model with the fields (email, password, first_name, last_name). The email field is unique and an index.

UserCreationForm: uses all fields, fails validation if the email already exists. Processes POST requests
UserUpdateForm: the same model, but doesn't allow to change the email. Because this field is excluded no issues there.
UserAuthenticationForm: includes only the email and password fields. The problem is, this should be used for authentication and validation fails because the email already exists.

Is there a way I can do this? That is, have the UserAuthenticationForm skip the email checking.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be a very odd tweak that might affect your code later, coding the form for authentication isn't that hard. You will be better following programming principle *separation of concerns* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns and letting each part of your software focus on its own objective.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think the logic separation is the issue. The form is doing something very spefic.

Comment: What I meant in the comment was the same you did in your answer. You have a form for creating/updating objects, don't use it for log users. Use it just for what it was created.

Comment: I get it now! ;) I'm already making the changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModelForms` are for creating/updating objects. Authentication doesn't modify the model instance (the `User`), therefore use a normal form instead.

From the docs:

> **The save() method**
>
> Every form produced by ModelForm also has a save() method. This method
>   creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form. A
>   subclass of ModelForm can accept an existing model instance as the
>   keyword argument instance; if this is supplied, save() will update
>   that instance. If it’s not supplied, save() will create a new instance
>   of the specified model.

If you weren't going to use this `save()`, method and you don't need most of the model fields either (only username/email and password), you would be throwing away most of the functionality offered by the `ModelForm`, so why would you use it in the first place?

Comment: I concur with your answer, but I think he ain't planning to use `safe`, just `validate.

Comment: Still, how do I use it for updating objects? It still says the email already exists.

Comment: You pass it the instance of the already existent object like this: `form = Form(request.POST, instance=db_object)`

Comment: Hmm.. I still get "This field is required." is it supposed to?

Comment: @AndréFratelli `class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ['email']` in 3 lines of course.

Comment: Adrián, not quite what I meant. If I do that then I can't update the email field. I want to allow the user to update only *some* fields. If the request includes an email address, then the address is updated, if the address is not in the request, then it remains unchanged, but still accepting validation. Can I do that?

Comment: @AndréFratelli see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134667/django-required-field-in-model-form then ;)

Comment: That does it! Thanks a lot ;)