# Django: Make certain fields in a ModelForm required=False

Tags: django, forms, field, required, modelform

How do I make certain fields in a ModelForm required=False?

If I have:

```
class ThatForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    widgets = {"text": Textarea(required=False)}
```

Or if I have:

```
class ThatForm(ModelForm):
  text = Textarea(required=False)
```

Django returns:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'
```

Comment: There's no form field type called `TextArea`, you have to use an ancestor of `Field`, probably the one called `CharField` and add a `TextArea` widget

Comment: Would it be possible to set the field to required=False without defining a static field and/or widget type?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

following from comments. Probably yes:

```
class ThatForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call parent's constructor
        super(ThatForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # there's a `fields` property now
        self.fields['desired_field_name'].required = False
```

Comment: @User I dont, but maybe official Django Docs could have: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/

Answer (score 49):

you ought to add `blank=True` to the corresponding model

[The documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types)

> If the model field has blank=True, then required is set to False on the form field. Otherwise, required=True.

Also see the [documentation for blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#blank) itself.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it is what `blank` is intended for

Comment: This is not always the solution: Imagine you have a field in a model that is compulsory, but you want to search for objects of that type with or without this restriction. Then you want the form to allow a search without that attribute. For instance you have colour as a required field in the model, but you might want search for objects that have a certain shape, regardless of the colour.

Comment: No solution is *always the solution*. But the solution I have presented is the best practice that ought to be used unless your situation is unusual (like the one you mentioned). In that case, a separate SO question would make sense. But OP doesn't mention any such situation, the question is very general and so should be the answer.

Comment: No, this solution is special solution, It’s a very common situation that you have a model with some required fields, e. g.  addresses with street, city, country all compulsory, but you want to search with a form (ModelForm) for just a part of the fields, e. g. just city and country. And I understood the OP like that. Your solution, that is very obvious for me, that you define the model fields as blank=True (sometimes in combination with null=True) works just in special cases. The general answer is the one by yedpodtrzitko.

Answer (score 36):

When we need to set required option on a bunch of fields we can:

```
class ThatForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field in self.Meta.required:
            self.fields[field].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'address',
            'postcode',
            'city',
            'state',
            'country',
            'company',
            'tax_id',
            'website',
            'service_notifications',
        )
        required = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'address',
            'postcode',
            'city',
            'country',
        )
```

Comment: Everything works like a charm. @SandeepBalagopal could you explain what exactly went wrong and show error?

Comment: tried this and the fields did not become required. If you look into the options in modelform, modelform is not having such an option https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L191

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal, do you want to tell that people voted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24045492/5992385 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1429646/5992385 are wrong

Comment: I didn't notice the init method you have overriden. It works. Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: Does anyone know why this is not a standard spec of ModelForms?

Comment: Great solution. However, I believe that all fields in a ModelForm are required by default, so wouldn't making a selected few "required" in the constructor be redundant? What one would need would be to select the optional ones and set THEM to required = False (leaving the rest in the default state of True).

Comment: @isilanes You sad "I believe that all fields in a ModelForm are required by default". But not all. Weather field is required on a ModelForm depends on the field parameters on its Model. And sometimes we need override such behavior by making non required field required.

Answer (score 5):

the following may be suitable

```
class ThatForm(ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score -17):

You could try this:

```
class ThatForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    requireds = 
    {
       'text':False,
    }
```

requireds must be under Meta.

Comment: Did you actually use this? Because I see no indication in the Django docs or source code, that this would work.