# Django skip option for form field

Tags: django

I have a ModelForm in django that generates a load of floating point field options.  This is being used for a ratings system, but I'd like to allow users to select "skip" on any of the catagories (NULL is allowed in the DB for each field).  Is there a native class in django for something like this that I'm missing?  If not, what would be the best way to achieve this e.g. such that

```
{% for field in form %}
<tr>
<td><label for="{{ field.label }}" class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label></td>
<td>{{ field }}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Would allow for something like {{ field.skip }} with a checkbox in the last column of a table?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is `required=False`

```
name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
```

This will make the field optional

**Edit**: For a Model Form, this might help you:

[Django: Make certain fields in a ModelForm required=False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045135/django-make-certain-fields-in-a-modelform-required-false)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this.  Thing is, I wanted to have an explicit checkbox such that users aren't confused and know that they are purposefully skipping an item.

Comment: @radpotato I believe you will have to bring in Mr. Javascript for this job.       http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/show-hide-divs-based-on-checkbox-selection-in-jquery.php