# Django widget not required by form despite setting

Tags: django, forms, wagtail

I have a form widget (for the `bio` field) which is not being required by the form (no validation, no HTML attribute set to `required`) despite me setting it explicitly in the form constructor ([as suggested in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134667/django-required-field-in-model-form)). When I say it is not required, I mean I can submit the form with the field empty (which I am blocked from doing for other fields):

`users/forms.py`:

```
from wagtail.admin.rich_text import get_rich_text_editor_widget

class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['bio'].required = True

    class Meta():
        model = _user_profiles.__model__
        fields = (
            'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'organisation',
            'bio', 'city', 'country', 'photo_file'
        )
        widgets = {
            'bio': get_rich_text_editor_widget('submission')
        }
```

If I set a breakpoint in `users/views.py` I can see that all the way until the end of the stack, the form field is correctly set to `'required'=True`, just like the `email` field which the form correctly requires, and unlike `city` which it does not require:

`users/views.py`:

```
> /root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py(151)get()
    150         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
--> 151         return self.render_to_response(context)
    152
ipdb> context['form'].fields['bio'].required
True
ipdb> context['form'].fields['email'].required
True
ipdb> context['form'].fields['city'].required
False
```

Any ideas why the field is not required?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble following your question (you haven't explicitly stated which field is showing as non-required, or how exactly that behaviour is manifesting itself on the form) but it's possible that you've run into this bug in Wagtail's RichTextField: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4549

Comment: Ah, that does indeed seem to be it, thank you! The form won't save and the field is required if I focus that field at some point.
I see the proposed solution was never actioned. Any tips from someone in my position?

Comment: Perhaps I can auto-focus on that input box with JS on page load.