# Django form.as_p DateField not showing input type as date

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Working on my first django app, and I have a model defined with some `DateFields`, and then a `ModelForm` off of that model i.e.

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    my_date = models.DateField('my date')
    ...

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
def show(request):
    form = MyModelForm
    template_name = 'myapp/show.html'
    return render(request,template_name,{'form':form})
```

and then in my html I use the `.as_p` to have django render the form for me

```
<form action="/show/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

But the `DateFields` have input type text, not date. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can create a custom widget:

```
from django import forms

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'my_date': DateInput()
        }
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Gotta love python/django

Comment: Anybody know why this is not default?

Comment: You can also achieve this by setting the field's `widget` when declaring it in the form: 
`start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))`

Comment: [There's a discussion on the Django issue tracker](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16630#comment:12) that explains why `type="date"` isn't generated by default.

Answer (score 53):

There's no need to subclass `DateInput`.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'my_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        }
```

Comment: For bounded forms use `forms.DateInput(format='%Y-%m-%d', attrs={'type': 'date'})` so instance's value can be displayed.

Answer (score 13):

```
start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

Comment: Cool, that's simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Using the [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks) package you can do this pretty simply by using:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{{form.date|attr:"type:date"}}
```

and making the field a date time field in your class:

```
date = forms.DateField()
```

Comment: I used to have this but using the same package's `render_field` template tag however it seems it stopped working now. I recently updated to Django 1.11, maybe it's no longer compatible...

Comment: Using widget_tweaks, you can also use `{% render_field form.date type="date" %}`

Answer (score 1):

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import MyModel
from django.forms.widgets import DateInput # need to import

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'my_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

## You can specify type attribute in attrs dictionary  which you want.

```
class AddProduct(forms.Form):
        name        = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}), required=True)
        amount      = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}), required=True)
        product_mfg = forms.CharField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'type':'date'}), required=True)
        product_exp = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'type':'date'}), required=True)
        department  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}), required=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we don't use `ModelForm` rather if we use `django.views.generic.edit.CreateView` only, there is a way for converting the default type of the input field (from text to date).

```
class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    ...

    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        form.fields['my_date'].widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        return form
```

This will render the input field like this,

```
<input type="date" name="my_date" required="" id="id_my_date">
```

Answer (score 0):

To use directly in forms.Form

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
input_type = 'date'

class Gym(forms.Form):
    starting_date = forms.DateField(widget = DateInput)
```

Comment: How this is the answer? Author is using the same format and the output results in text input. Even django documentation it is clearly mentioned DateInput widget type is text.

Answer (score -1):

### Installation

- Run `pip install django-datetimepicker`
- Add `'datetimepicker'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

### Basic usage

Here is an example of how to use the widget.

. Assign the `DateTimePicker` to a `DateTimeField`, `DateField` or `TimeField`.

```
from django import forms
from datetimepicker.widgets import DateTimePicker


class SampleForm(forms.Form):
     datetime = forms.DateTimeField(widget=DateTimePicker(),)
```