# How to change the input of django form field, so HTML is rendered with specific input-type

Tags: python, django, forms, input

Following situation:
I want to have a small form in which a user can enter a day, a start time and an end time. For each of this three fields I want to have a date/timepicker. As I do not want to use Bootstrap or jQuery because my project is very small and I just want to keep it small I wanted to use the native HTML pickers which are shown when changing the input-type of a field to 'date' or 'time'.

I tried to change the input types of my Fields according to this Question/Answer: 
[Django form.as_p DateField not showing input type as date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846048/django-form-as-p-datefield-not-showing-input-type-as-date)
This did not work for me.

This is my form, with the inputs. There are two approches, for the DateInput I tried it like it was shown in the linked question, for the TimeInput I tried to override the widget.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from django.utils import timezone
from django.forms.widgets import TimeInput

from .models import Occupancy


class UltraDateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'


class UltraTimeInput(TimeInput):
    input_type = 'time'


class OccupancyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    occupancy_date = forms.DateField()
    start_time = forms.TimeField()
    end_time = forms.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Occupancy
        exclude = ['user', 'start', 'end']
        fields = ['occupancy_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 
                 'notes']
        widgets = {
            'occupancy_date': UltraDateInput(),
            'start_time': UltraTimeInput(),
            'end_time': UltraTimeInput()
        }
```

The strange ultra names are because I thought that my custom widgets are maybe shadowed by some much more deeper logic, but it did not helped.

I expect the widget to change the input type of my generated fields to date and time in my HTML file I get in the end, but they still remain to be simple textinputs.

Comment: Instead of subclassing `DateInput`, have you tried: `'occupancy_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}`?

Comment: Yes, does not work either.

Comment: Does removing or changing the earlier `occupancy_date = forms.DateField()` change anything?

Comment: Yes, then the program crashes. This field is not on the model and I have to define it there for my logic.

Comment: defining it like `occupancy_date = forms.DateField(attrs={'type': 'date')` should work then. If not, may have other high level config problems

Comment: How are you displaying these fields in the template?

Comment: `{% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% block content %}

 <form method="post" novalidate>
   {% csrf_token %}
   <table border="1">
     {{ form }}
   </table>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
 {% endblock %}`

Comment: you can use [https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks] (django-widget-tweaks) module to achieve this in the frontend