# Why is Django widgets for TimeInput not showing

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create a `TimeInput` field in a form and noticed that [the widget isn't showing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nxXq.png#1). But when I check the `localhost:8000/admin`, I see [the widget showing up correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nxXq.png).

My code is as follows. For `models.py`,

```
class TimeLimit(models.Model):
    before = models.TimeField(blank=True, default=time(7, 0)) # 7AM
    after = models.TimeField(blank=True, default=time(23, 0)) # 11PM
```

For `views.py`,

```
class UpdateTimeLimitView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    model = TimeLimit
    template_name = 'accounts/update_time_limit.html'
    form_class = UpdateTimeLimitForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('accounts:user_profile') + '?username=' + self.request.GET['username']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(UpdateTimeLimitView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['username'] = self.request.GET['username']
        return data
```

For `forms.py`,

```
class UpdateTimeLimitForm(forms.Form):
    time_error = {'required': 'This field is required.',
                  'invalid': 'Please enter valid Hour:Minute values.'}

    before = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M'))
    after = forms.TimeField(widget=TimeInput(format='%H:%M'))

    class Meta:
        model = TimeLimit
```

Finally, the relevant part for fields in `update_time_limit.html`,

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}({{ field.help_text }}):</label>
            <br />
            {{ field }}<br /><br /> and
        {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary done-btn" type="submit" value="Update Time Limit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Is there anything that I'm missing or doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django admin uses [`AdminTimeWidget`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/432623603ced935132798c22214f866af5b5f37c/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L70) to display time fields, not the `TimeInput` widget that you are using in your code.

There isn't a documented way to reuse the `AdminTimeWidget` outside of the Django admin. Getting it to work is very hacky (see the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/38916#38916), which is probably out of date), so it's probably better to use a different widget.

Comment: Thank you! After searching around, I also saw a similar answer to yours on StackOverflow here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450463/django-datetimewidget-not-showing-up]. I'll leave the quote here in case other people find it useful: "The Django DateInput widget doesn't render anything but a plain text input. It does however validate the user's input against a variety of formats, so it's not useless.

Most people would expect it to behave in the same way as the date picker found in the Django Admin interface, so it's definitely a little confusing."

Answer (score 0):

convert datetime.time(7, 0) to string work for me.

`data['before'] = data['before'].strftime('%H:%M:%S')`