# Django forms: how to display media (javascript) for a DateTimeInput widget?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

Hello (please excuse me for my bad english ;) ),

Imagine the classes bellow:

**models.py**

```
from django import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name=_('content type'))
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('object id'))
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    published_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    published_at = forms.DateTimeField(required=False, widget=DateTimeInput)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
form django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class MyModelInline(generic.GenericStackedInline):
    model = MyModel
    form = MyModelForm

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MyModelInline]
```

**Problem**: the `<script>` tags for javascript from the DateTimeInput widget don't appear in the admin site (adding a new MyModel object). i.e. these two lines :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/media/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/media/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>
```

Please, do you have any idea to fix it ?

Thank you very much and have a good day :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard DateTimeWidget doesn't include any javascript. The widget used in the admin is a different one - `django.contrib.admin.widgets.AdminSplitDateTime` - and this includes the javascript.

Comment: Specific code to implement this solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/38916#38916