# DateTime field in Django form model

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, django-forms

When using `DateTimeField` in `ModelForm`s, they look like text fields. How can I make them look like in the admin?  (When I go to the admin and add a show I see the fields as date fields)

```
# models.py
class Show(models.Model):
    ...
    start_time = models.DateTimeField("Event Time")
    sale_end_time = models.DateTimeField("Sale End Time")

class ShowForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Show 

# views.py
def createshow(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ShowForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/showsaved')
    else:
        form = ShowForm()
        return render(request, 'BizCreateShow.html', {'ShowForm' : form})
```

In the template:

```
<form class="form-horizontal well" action="" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
    {{ ShowForm }} </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with django widgets. It is very simple and easy to implement. Bellow are the details how you can use this using widgets.

in **forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class ShowForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Show 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ShowForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['start_time'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()
        self.fields['sale_end_time'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()
```

in **template**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my_admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/admin/js/core.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/forms.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/base.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/global.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/admin/css/widgets.css"/>
```

This is it. Please let me know if i am not much clear. Or you are facing any error in it.

Comment: Thanks, when I try that I get an error: "Undefined variable: widgets" on this line: self.fields['start_time'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()

Comment: try this "from django.contrib.admin import widgets" may it will solve your problem.

Comment: Note that in 1.4+ you call the static files differently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15292176/1863061

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use something like jQuery UI's [datepicker widget](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

> The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field. Focus on the
>   input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a
>   small overlay. Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur the
>   input), or hit the Esc key to close. If a date is chosen, feedback is
>   shown as the input's value.

Comment: Thanks! but how can I give the input field a class or ID to use in the javascript if the form generates in the model?

Comment: Also- I need the time in the same field, don't I? It only lets me select the date.

Comment: Ok, I used $("form input[name='start_time']").click(function () { 
    $("form input[name='start_time']").datepicker();
});

Comment: It needs to be said that this method will NOT work in formsets.