# Django - birthdate fildset as form widget

Tags: django, forms

If I have in forms.py:

```
birthdate = forms.DateTimeField()
```

and html:

```
<fieldset class='birthday-picker'>
    <select class='birth-year' name='birth[year]'></select>
    <select class='birth-month' name='birth[month]'></select>
    <select class='birth-day' name='birth[day]'></select>
    <input type='hidden' name='birthdate' />
</fieldset>
```

Do I need create a new widget or there is an answer for this? If there is no answer i will be grateful for every advice how to do this

Answer (score 15):

There is a built in widget that already does that.

```
from django.forms import extras

class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget)
```

Comment: That really helped! A lot of people missed this nice extra widget

Comment: Update for version >= 1.9. SelectDateWidget is in django.forms and not in django.forms.extras anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If the html doesn't have to be exactly like this, you might get away easier with a pure javascript solution like the [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) or use [djangos own admin datewidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/38916#38916).

Comment: I don't like this datepicker. I like facebook like one: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/birthdaypicker. It seems to I need to work on this a little, but not now. I need sleep, then go. I will use your advices. Thanks. See You later aligatore.

Answer (score 0):

for version >= 1.9

```
from django import forms

class Some_Form(forms.Form):
    birthday = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget
        )
```

or

use jquery-ui

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    })
```