# Django ModelForm with Admin Widgets

Tags: python, django, django-admin, web

I have created models and from the models, I created `ModelForms`. However, I noticed that the widgets generated from the `ModelForm` are not as same as the widgets when I am in Admin pages.

How can I:

1. Get the same widget as the ones in admin pages. Those are awesome. The foreign key field comes with 'plus' icon that enables you to add new item being referenced to.
2. Date time widget has 'Now' button that enables you to populate the field instantly with the current time.
3. Is there any other cool plugin out there for the widgets? So far all I got is meh, just plain html widget that doesnt make sense even for field like Datetime (it generates normal plain input control).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form 
The answer for this one explains what you need. If you figure out what widgets are you will be able to write your own, it's really easy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look to django/contrib/admin/widgets.py  You will find here the admin site widgets. Then in you form, make something like:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget

class MyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'date': AdminDateWidget(),
        }
```

Make sure that your template includes the required media files (css, js)

I also recommend to look at [django-floppyforms](https://github.com/brutasse/django-floppyforms) which is a very nice lib if you want better widgets

Comment: just a quick question, does floppyforms have feature like the admin ( now for datetime field, auto add button for foreign key etc)

Comment: There is a date widget. See https://github.com/brutasse/django-floppyforms/blob/master/docs/widgets.rst. I think I never used this one but It worths a look.