# How to use the date picker used in django 1.11 admin site in custom form?

Tags: python, django

I want to use the date picker in my ModelForm that is used in django admin site but I don't know how to use because i am new in Django so help me to solve this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this  [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form) [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938939/django-modelform-with-admin-widgets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import SampleModel

class SampleModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        widgets = {'date_field': SelectDateWidget()}}
```