# Time input format in AdminTimeWidget in django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

I use admin calendar and time widgets in django form: [description, how to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form)

But widget input time format is: "%H:%M:%S". I need "%H:%M". Here is my code:

```
class CorporateOrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Order
        #exclude=('giving_address_comment','giving_address','comment')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CorporateOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['order_date'].widget = widgets.AdminDateWidget()
        self.fields['order_time'].widget = widgets.AdminTimeWidget(format='%H:%M')
```

Last row is important: I try to change format. Here is AdminTimeWidget code:

```
class AdminTimeWidget(forms.TimeInput):
    class Media:
        js = (settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX + "js/calendar.js",
              settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX + "js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js")

    def __init__(self, attrs={}, format=None):
        super(AdminTimeWidget, self).__init__(attrs={'class': 'vTimeField', 'size': '8'}, format=format)
```

And here is TimeInput code:

```
class TimeInput(Input):
    input_type = 'text'
    format = '%H:%M:%S'     # '14:30:59'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, format=None):
      super(TimeInput, self).__init__(attrs)
      if format:
          self.format = format
          self.manual_format = True
      else:
          self.format = formats.get_format('TIME_INPUT_FORMATS')[0]
          self.manual_format = False
```

It's not work, time format not changed. Where is the error?...

Comment: Can you include the body of `TimeInput.__init__`?

Comment: When you say, "I need %H:%S", do you mean, "I need %H:%M"?

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
class CorporateOrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Order
        widgets = {
            'order_date': widgets.AdminDateWidget(),
            'order_time': widgets.AdminTimeWidget(format='%H:%M')
        }
```