# Does not work AdminSplitDateTime

Tags: python, django, datetime, datetimepicker

I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form) ( Use `%YYYY-%MM-%DD %HH-%MM` format ) and repeat all, but this does not work. Widget for datetime look as a splitDateTime, not as datetimepicker in adminSplitDateTime. This is my code in form.py

```
class ReservationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reserve

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReservationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['datetime_reservation'].widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime()
        self.fields['datetime_reservation'].label = "(month/day/year hour/minutes)"
```

And my template file.

```
{% extends "lfs/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load lfs_tags %}
{% load l10n %}

{% block content %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my_admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>
    <h1 class="first-heading">{% trans 'Reservation' %}</h1>
    <form action="{% url reserve_form  %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% localize on %}
        {% for field in form %}
        <div class="field">
            <div class="label">
                {{ field.label_tag }}:
            </div>

            {% if field.errors %}
                <div class="error">
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div>
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endlocalize %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Also I add "admin/jsi18n/" to my urlConf such as

```
url(r'^admin/jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', name="django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog"),
```

And second question. I tried do this, becouse I can't change DateTimeField format to `'%d/%m%y %H:%M'`. I tried use `DateTimeField(input_formats="%d/%m/%y %H:%M")`, but this does not work and I have error such as `"Use %YYYY-%MM-%DD %HH-%MM format"`. I tried use SplitDateTime and set format to `input_date_formats "%d/%m/%y"` but this does not work too. Maybe in this field this format is not support and I must write custom field for this format?

Thanks in advance for your help.