# need a time widget or clock widget

Tags: python, django, time, django-widget

is there anything like a timewidget or clock widget in Django which will help me to input data into a form for appointment date (like we have calendar or date widget).

i have my date widget working with the below code in my forms.py:

```
import datetime
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
mydate = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)
```

is there anything like this for time widget

Comment: have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#splitdatetimewidget check this out.

Comment: Karthik .. i have tried that it gives me a text box which takes time as input.But i need a widget which will help me select or pick the time, more like a clock