# How to change the appearance of the Admin date widget in front end

Tags: django

I integrated the Django Admin datewidget into my front end. I want to change the appearance and some text in the calendar that appears. So, I found out that somehow, the script that is being invoked is DateTimeShortcuts.js. I tried to change the code through su vi and saved the changes, but no change appears in the output. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong. I pasted the link to the screenshot to make it easier for you to understand what I'm trying to do. Help will really be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

http://imageshack.us/a/img31/2977/screenshot20121016at709.png

Saadat

Comment: "I tried to change the code through su vi and saved the changes" — 
Do you mean that you changed the JavaScript file that ships with Django?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using another library for your front-end datepicker widget such as the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). This is because getting the Django datepicker widget working on the frontend is quite fiddly. However, if you insist on using it, you'll the find this Stack Overflow question (and accompanying answers) useful: [Using Django time/date widgets in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form). I suspect the right scripts are not being loaded (or are being loaded in the wrong order).