# SplitSelectDateTime Widget

Tags: django

```
 forms.py 

 class KEBReading_form(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model=KEBReading
    exclude=("truepower_consumed","powerfactor",)

    datetime = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.SplitSelectDateTimeWidget(hour_step=2, \
    minute_step=15, second_step=30, twelve_hr=True, years=[2008,2009,2010]))
```

In the Database i have used a field called DateTime but in my web page i want it to be separate date and time for the user to enter. how do i make it work using splitSelectDateTimeWidget. i tried but it din work. it displayed as a single field called datetime only forthe user to enter.

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet SplitSelectDateTimeWidget
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1206/

also here's how to use django admin datetime widgets
[Using Django time/date widgets in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form)