# django admin datetime widget (calendar) in a custom form

Tags: python, django, calendar, widget

I cannot add an admin calendar widget in my form. How to do it?

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


FIELDNUM = (('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'),
            ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'), ('6', '6'), ('7', '7'), ('8', '8'),
            ('9', '9'), ('10', '10'))

FIELDNAMES = (('test', 'test'), ('kostas', 'kostas'), ('kaka', 'kaka'))

class Reservation(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField("Field Name*", choices=FIELDNAMES, max_length=100)
    fieldnum = models.CharField("Field Number*", choices=FIELDNUM, max_length=2)
    date = models.DateField("Date*")
    time = models.TimeField("Time*")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.field_name, self.date, self.time, self.date_time)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("field_name", "fieldnum", "date", "time")
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from booking.models import Reservation

class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        exclude = ['user']
```

I rendered my form as paragraph in my template.

Where to call the widget and how to set it in my template in order for it to work?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is not to use the widget from `django.contrib.admin.widgets` but rather a third party widget such as the `Datepicker` from jQuery UI.

All you have to do is to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) in your template and add this script

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".date_picker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Where `.date_picker` is the name of the class of the form input related to the `date` field of your `Reservation` model.

In order for Django to add this `class='date_picker'` to the generated form input related to `date`, you have to slightly modify your `ModelForm`. More specifically,

```
from django import forms
from booking.models import Reservation

class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        exclude = ['user']
        widgets = {
            'date' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'class' : 'date_picker'})
        }
```

This will have the effect of rendering `<input type='text' ... class='date_picker' />` when you call `{{ form.as_p }}` in your template, and jQuery UI does the rest.

By the way, a small improvement to your `models.py` would be to use python's list comprehension. Namely

```
FIELDNUM = (('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'), ('6', '6'), ('7', '7'), ('8', '8'),
        ('9', '9'), ('10', '10'))
```

is equivalent to

```
FIELDNUM = [(str(i), str(i)) for i in range(1,11)]
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't get it. can you please explain how to use this in my template when i render my form like that 'code'<form action="/reservations/add/" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">Post</button>
                    </form>

Comment: sorry but i didn't get it. can you please explain how to use this in my template when i render my form like that  <form action="/reservations/add/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }} <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">Post</button> </form>

Comment: i did what you suggested but i dont get the datepicker in my form