# In django(1.5.4) model form how do i get the admin type date and time selector?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
from django import form
from awesomite.models import tasks

    class todoform(forms.ModelForm):

        title = forms.CharField(max_length=250, help_text="Please enter a title")
        description = forms.CharField(max_length=400, help_text="Please enter title description")
        time = forms.DateTimeField()

        class Meta:
            model = tasks
            fields = ('title','description','time')
```

In the above code i wish to have a dateselector and time selector when the form is being displayed(as seen in the admin page).I searched for this in other references and found it hard to implement or follow. Im fairly new to django.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
from django import form
from awesomite.models import tasks
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class todoform(forms.ModelForm):

    title = forms.CharField(max_length=250, help_text="Please enter a title")
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=400, help_text="Please enter title description")
    time = forms.DateTimeField(widget=widgets.AdminSplitDateTime())

    class Meta:
        model = tasks
        fields = ('title','description','time')
```

You should include other Media files in your form->Media class or directly in template

(see -> [Using Django time/date widgets in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form))