# Django: Timefield widget not showing in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

TLDR: how do I get my timefield to show in the template?

I customized my ModelForm in the class meta. For some reason, only the label change is shown, not the widget change.
Here is my code:

```
class MenuCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = (
            'name',
            'monday',
            'availability_begin_mon',
            'availability_end_mon',
        labels = {
            'availability_begin_mon': ('Begin Montag'),
            'availability_end_mon': ('Ende Montag'),
        widgets = {
            'availability_begin_mon': forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M'),
            'availability_end_mon': forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M'),
```

And here is the template I used:

```
<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type='submit'>Änderungen speichern</button>
</form>
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, django forms does not show Date/Time widget in custom forms.
If you want that, there's a hack-ish way to do it.
please refer to the following discussion
[Using Django time/date widgets in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form)

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!