# How can I use HTML5 date/time widgets with Django's SplitDateTimeField?

Tags: django-forms

The default [SplitDateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.SplitDateTimeField) uses [SplitDateTimeWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SplitDateTimeWidget), which uses `<input type="text">` fields. With modern browsers and HTML5, we could use `<input type="date">` and `type="time"` to get a much more usable interface, without any Javascript. How can I do this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `django.forms.SplitDateTimeField`, drop in the following `SplitDateTimeField` that overrides the `type` attributes for the widgets to use the HTML5 versions.

Browser support may vary, [but is now pretty good](https://caniuse.com/?search=type%3Ddate).

```py
from django import forms


class SplitDateTimeWidget(forms.SplitDateTimeWidget):
    """
    A widget that splits datetime input into two <input type="text"> boxes,
    and uses HTML5 'date' and 'time' inputs.
    """

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, date_format=None, time_format=None, date_attrs=None, time_attrs=None):
        date_attrs = date_attrs or {}
        time_attrs = time_attrs or {}
        if "type" not in date_attrs:
            date_attrs["type"] = "date"
        if "type" not in time_attrs:
            time_attrs["type"] = "time"
        return super().__init__(
            attrs=attrs, date_format=date_format, time_format=time_format, date_attrs=date_attrs, time_attrs=time_attrs
        )


class SplitDateTimeField(forms.SplitDateTimeField):
    widget = SplitDateTimeWidget
```

Usage:

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_datetime_field = SplitDateTimeField()
```